# How to Get the First Different Character Between 2 Strings in Objective-C (for iOS)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, character, loops

I know I can loop through each character of two NSString objects using characterAtIndex: and compare them, but this approach would be very expensive if I use this function frequently.

Is there anything built in for this, or a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Why would this be expensive? It's O(n) with N being the size of the string.

Comment: My research on StackOverflow lead me to this assumption -- do you think it would have the same performance as the approach described by C0deH4cker below?

Comment: The only performance savings I can think of would be the bounds checking that characterAtIndex does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way i can think of is to get a C string from it, and then iterate through the strings.

Just a quick example (fix it to your liking):

```
const char* myCString = [myNSStringInstance UTF8String];
const char* string2 = [nsstring2 UTF8String];

// Assume same length. You can fix this
for(i = 0; i < strlen(myCString); i++) {
    if(myCString[i] != string2[i]) {
        // Do something here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode tells me that I should be using "const char *" rather than "char * here". Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, UTF8String needs to be `const`, otherwise you could easily modify the contents out from underneath the NSString (which is immutable by design)

Comment: Note that when you call the -UTF8String method you're converting the string from UTF-16 encoding to UTF-8 encoding.  You're asking the NSString class to duplicate the string memory, and iterate over each character to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8.  How is that more efficient than simply calling -characterAtIndex directly?

Comment: I would compute strlen(myCString) once and store it in a variable so that it doesn't have to compute it for every loop iteration since we are looking for efficiency here.

Comment: Yes, this code can be improved as it was just an example that I typed up. Darren: it would be faster as it would avoid the Obj-C method invocation overhead for each iteration and would simply compare bytes of memory. And yes, you would want to compute the length beforehand, but as I said in the comment, you would have to rewrite this to find the length of the shorter string so you don't run into a Segmentation Fault. Also, the -[NSString cString] method is deprecated so that should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

It's a litte hackish, but you could get the c-string for each and then use pointer indexing. Same basic algorithm as your mentioned idea, but theoretically as efficient as you could reasonably expect a solution to be (just looking at two memory addresses and comparing their contents.

Pseudo code:

```
char *stringA = [stringA cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char *stringB = [stringB cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int mismatchIndex = -1;
for(int i = 0; i<shorterStringLength; i++) {
    if (stringA[i] != stringB[i]) {
        mismatchIndex = i;
        break;
    } 
}
```